# Android Studio Electric Eel - Windows - JDK 11 - Do not allow to build projects even when you make a new one

Tags: java, android, windows, gradle

I updated Android Studio to Electic Eel version (2022.1.1). I was working in a project but after this update there is no way to build the project. When I open it I get this error in `build.gradle`

[image: First error]

I tried to use the Run options recomendations but did not work, then I change the Android Gradle Plugin Version goning to File > Project Struture > Project, then set it to 7.5

[image: Android Gradle Plugin Version]

After this change the error type change to this:

[image: New error]

This is the code on the Gradle files:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application' version '7.4' apply false
   id 'com.android.library' version '7.4' apply false
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

**settigns.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue changing the `Android Gradle Plugin` Version and `Gradle Version` olders version I went to **File > Project Structure > Project**

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]